# how to create an object inside a fragment ? is it possible or not

Tags: android-fragments

```
public class Fragmentone<Interface1> extends Fragment{

    public Interface1 Interface;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
        ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Interface = new Interface1 (this);

        return inflater.inflate(
        R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
    }
}
```

it is showing an error

> Cannot instantiate the type Interface1

Comment: Learn what is interface first

Comment: Thank for suggestion i went through the interface concept and its detail explanation. i have to use the constructor of another class in this class how can do that

Comment: Interfaces have no constructors. They are not base classes you need to learn object oriented programming